# geoSpatial & Location based search in google appengine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, search, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I want to achieve something like the map drag search on airbnb (https://www.airbnb.com/s/Paris--France?source=ds&page=1&s_tag=PNoY_mlz&allow_override%5B%5D=)

I am saving the data like this in datastore

```
 user.lat = float(lat)
     user.lon = float(lon)
     user.geoLocation = ndb.GeoPt(float(lat),float(lon))
```

and whenever I drag & drop map or zoom in or zoom out  I get following parameters in my controller

```
    def get(self):
    """
    This is an ajax function. It gets the place name, north_east, and south_west
    coordinates. Then it fetch the results matching the search criteria and
    create a result list. After that it returns the result in json format.
    :return: result
    """
    self.response.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
    results = []
    north_east_latitude = float(self.request.get('nelat'))
    north_east_longitude = float(self.request.get('nelon'))
    south_west_latitude = float(self.request.get('swlat'))
    south_west_longitude = float(self.request.get('swlon'))
    points = Points.query(Points.lat<north_east_latitude,Points.lat>south_west_latitude)
    for row in points:
        if  row.lon > north_east_longitude and row.lon < south_west_longitude:
            listingdic = {'name': row.name, 'desc': row.description, 'contact': row.contact, 'lat': row.lat, 'lon': row.lon}
            results.append(listingdic)
    self.write(json.dumps({'listings':results}))
```

My model class is given below

```
class Points(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    contact = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    lat = ndb.FloatProperty(required=True)
    lon = ndb.FloatProperty(required=True)
    geoLocation = ndb.GeoPtProperty()
```

**I want to improve the query.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is what you have working? Is it not good enough? What exactly needs to be improved? BTW, you probably don't need three different properties just to store the location as this `user.geoLocation = ndb.GeoPt(float(lat),float(lon))` should be enough. Also, not sure how good datastore is with geo searches (from what I've heard - it isn't)  but I've had good experience wth [GAE's Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/) and its [GeoPoint class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/geopointclass).

Comment: @MihailRussu   I just want to get those results which resides in the current map bounds. and for this this we have to check 4 conditions I am checking two of them in m query and two of them in a loop to filter it further I want this thing to be optimized e.g 4 conditions should be checked in a query only. Because if I will loop through the results it will slow the whole process. and if we talk about ndb.GeoPtProperty() I am unable to access the individual lat and lng from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot improve the solution by checking all 4 conditions in the query because ndb queries do not support inequality filters on multiple properties. From [NDB Queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries) (emphasis mine):

> **Limitations:** The Datastore enforces some restrictions on queries.
>   Violating these will cause it to raise exceptions. For example,
>   combining too many filters, **using inequalities for multiple
>   properties**, or combining an inequality with a sort order on a
>   different property are all currently disallowed. Also filters
>   referencing multiple properties sometimes require secondary indexes to
>   be configured.

and

> **Note:** As mentioned earlier, the Datastore rejects queries using inequality filtering on more than one property.