# How to build a query dynamically, based on conditions?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I want to query the datastore on a range (0-4) of possible criteria, based on a user request. Queries in NDB are built as follows:

```
query = Account.query(Account.userid >= 40, Account.userid < 50)
```

Is there any way I could do something like:

```
myfilter = []
myfilter.push('Account.userid >= 40')
myfilter.push('Account.userid < 50')
myfilter.push('Account.name == "John"')
query = Account.query(*myfilter)
```

There may be anywhere from 0 to 4 filter arguments, depending on conditionals. My assumption (which could be wrong) is that it is more optimal to omit a filter than have a catch-all (ex. Account.userid == *) if there is no need for it.

I know you can chain filters but since query objects are immutable, not sure this helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. From [Filtering by Property Values](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop):

> Instead of specifying an entire query filter in a single expression,
>   you may find it more convenient to build it up in steps: for example:
>
> ```
> query1 = Account.query()  # Retrieve all Account entitites
> query2 = query1.filter(Account.userid >= 40)  # Filter on userid >= 40
> query3 = query2.filter(Account.userid < 50)  # Filter on userid < 50 too
> ```
>
> `query3` is equivalent to the `query` variable from the previous
>   example. Note that query objects are immutable, so the construction of
>   `query2` does not affect `query1` and the construction of `query3`
>   does not affect `query1` or `query2`.

You can use such incremental query build technique to conditionally add filters as needed. For example (this assumes an overall AND between the optional conditions):

```
query = Account.query()  # Retrieve all Account entitites
loggin.error(query)

if filter_by_userid:
    query = query.filter(Account.userid >= 40, Account.userid < 50)
    loggin.error(query)

if filter_by_username:
    query = query.filter(Account.name == "John")
    loggin.error(query)

loggin.error('Final: %s' % query)
```

The above snippet specifically takes advantage of the imutability of the query object, each assignment to the `query` variable actually storing the *new* query object obtained by applying the respective filter. Confirmed by the associated log messages.

Comment: I initially thought that because query objects are not mutable, this wouldn't work. But I found a way to make it work. It's not super elegant because you have to define a query for each filter even if you're not using them. (For example, query2 has to be defined even if you don't care about that specific filter). Anyway, it's good enough for my purposes.

Comment: What do you mean by "you don't care about that specific filter"?

Comment: if the parameters are dynamic and you are using inequality filters you would likely have missing indexes right @DanCornilescu?  unless you could enumerate all possible queries you think are possible and provide an index for each one I think this sort of arbitrary querying is just something thats not a good fit for datastore

Comment: @jcjones1515 Of course the indexes for all possible final queries (i.e. all possible combination of conditions and corresponding filters) need to be ready/serving. Without the indexes the queries would not work, regardless of how they're written (to me the question is mostly about how to write the queries nicer).

Comment: @DanCornilescu Thanks. That's similar to what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 2):

There is a more elegant way of doing this. And btw is more dynamic:

```
def build_query_by(ndb_class, filters, sorts):
    """
    ndb_class: the ndb model class to query
    filters: a list of tuples of properties, operations and values
    sorts: a list of tuples of properties and order symbol
    """
    q = ndb_class.query()
    for prop, operation, value in filters:
        if operation == '==':
            q = q.filter(getattr(ndb_class, prop) == value)
        elif operation == '>=':
            q = q.filter(getattr(ndb_class, prop) >= value)
        elif operation == '<=':
            q = q.filter(getattr(ndb_class, prop) <= value)
        # more operations...

    for prop, symbol in sorts:
        if symbol == '-':
            q = q.order(-getattr(ndb_class, prop))
        else:
            q = q.order(getattr(ndb_class, prop))
    return q
```

Comment: With care, tho: can't use inequality filters on more than 1 property and can't use inequality filters on one property and sorting on another. See other limitations quoted in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41583096/4495081 The code might not look so neat after including protection for them.